# Drawing clickable grid with background

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently exploring my options for drawing (javafx) limited 2D (N x N) grid where crossing are clickable elements.

Example: (red rectangles are example of clickable areas - meaning area is bound to particular intersection, all crossings should be such rectangle).

[image]

Requirements:

- Grid is resizable (x/y scale is preserved).
- "Crossings" can receive mouse events.

As of now it's either make GridPane that will hold rectangles that receive events. Each rectangle would have background drawing corresponding to its position in grid (so rectangles on border have different background).

Other things I've considered is making transparent rectangles placed on GridPane that itself draws background.

Now my question here is - what would be best/proper way of doing such thing. What tools can be useful to me?

Comment: "Best" in what sense? Surely "best" is entirely a matter of opinion. Just try the different ways and see what works out the way you want it (i.e. what meets whatever your definition of "best" is).

Comment: @James_D Best as in javafx provides tools that make code shorter and clearer. There are probably quite few ways of doing same thing, but there is always one that will by opinion of many become convention. I am asking here what tools would you choose (so that I don't have to reinvent techniques and follow some good practice that I might not know).

Comment: That just sounds like you are asking for opinions, and so it is off topic.

Comment: Question is not if ToolA is better than ToolB and why, but WHAT is the tool.

Comment: I would hold all the clickable rectangle shapes in a list and use the .contains method in the shape class.